# MySQL - Join tables to a custom list/array of values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to know if it's possible to join tables into a custom set of values in MySQL. For example, I have a set of dates (outside the database). I would like to get the matched joins in a single query so that I can easily loop through the result. Like:

`Data outside database`

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-04-08 |
| 2021-04-09 |
| 2021-04-10 |
| 2021-04-11 |
| 2021-04-12 |

The Database may look like

`Table: transactions`

| id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-08 | 500 |
| 2 | 2021-04-08 | 600 |
| 3 | 2021-04-10 | 350 |

I want the result to be like:

| Date | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-08 | 1100 |
| 2021-04-09 | 0 |
| 2021-04-10 | 350 |
| 2021-04-11 | 0 |
| 2021-04-12 | 0 |

In other words, I want to do:

```
SELECT transactions.date, SUM(amount) FROM ["2021-04-08", "2021-04-09", "2021-04-10", ...] INNER JOIN transactions ON current_value=transactions.date GROUP BY transactions.date
```

Comment: No , mysql cannot get data from outside the db, You could fiddle about with csv engine but simpler to import data.

Comment: *Data outside database* You must send this data into the database as rowset (or convert scalar list to rowset in a query).

Comment: @Akina How do I convert scalar list to rowset? Actually, I wanted to fetch the data for a graph and I want to fill the value with zero if no record for that date is found in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE transactions (id INT, `date` DATE, amount INT);
> INSERT INTO transactions VALUES 
> (1,   '2021-04-08',   500),
> (2,   '2021-04-08',   600),
> (3,   '2021-04-10',   350);
> SELECT * FROM transactions;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | amount
> -: | :--------- | -----:
>  1 | 2021-04-08 |    500
>  2 | 2021-04-08 |    600
>  3 | 2021-04-10 |    350
> ```

> ```
> SET @outside := '2021-04-08,2021-04-09,2021-04-10,2021-04-11,2021-04-12';
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE
> cte AS ( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@outside, ',', 1) `date`,
>                 TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(@outside, ',', 1) FROM @outside)) slack
>          UNION ALL
>          SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(slack, ',', 1),
>                 TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(slack, ',', 1) FROM slack))
>          FROM cte
>          WHERE slack != '' )
> SELECT `date`, COALESCE(SUM(transactions.amount), 0) `sum`
> FROM cte
> LEFT JOIN transactions USING (`date`)
> GROUP BY `date`
> ORDER BY `date`
> ```
>
> ```
> date       |  sum
> :--------- | ---:
> 2021-04-08 | 1100
> 2021-04-09 |    0
> 2021-04-10 |  350
> 2021-04-11 |    0
> 2021-04-12 |    0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `date`, COALESCE(SUM(transactions.amount), 0) `sum`
> FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@outside, ',', '","'), '"]'),
>                 "$[*]" COLUMNS (`date` DATE path "$")) jsontable
> LEFT JOIN transactions USING (`date`)
> GROUP BY `date`
> ORDER BY `date`
> ```
>
> ```
> date       |  sum
> :--------- | ---:
> 2021-04-08 | 1100
> 2021-04-09 |    0
> 2021-04-10 |  350
> 2021-04-11 |    0
> 2021-04-12 |    0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bcec648464ab9a1ee5b0ed709f371ba)*

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for... Another solution was to create a table of dates or query the database more than 100 times... This looks better!

Comment: @AjithGopi If server version allows (8.0.4+) then I'd recommend to use JSON array as outside dates list (or convert CSV to JSON in the query) and JSON_TABLE() for parsing. Answer updated.